# How can I get the current colour scheme on KDE from a non-qt application

Tags: linux, kde

Suppose I was writing my own text editor in a GUI toolkit that isn't Qt, and I wanted for it to inherit the colour scheme of the Qt applications.

What is the best way to do so?

`kreadconfig5` is a potential option but it is tedious and frankly extremely brittle.

Comment: Do you know what kreadconfig5 reads? Can you read that using other means? That seems to me to be a good first step in this journey.